# Get info for all current Autofac-managed instances

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I need a diagnostic/admin page to show what Autofac is managing at the current point in time. Good for finding leaks and bugs.

[There is a way](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/03/05/instance-counting-with-autofac/) to count the number of objects Autofac has been resolving. However it's heavy and shouldn't be used in production.

[There is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600468/7059613) to log all resolutions. Similarly, it shouldn't be used in production.

Unlike those solutions, all I need is a snapshot of currently managed objects. Is this possible, without capturing every resolution event and storing it (as done above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Autofac* will *only* create instances of services, except for `IDisposable` services it doesn't keep track of any services. If you want to have all resolved service, you will have to monitor and log them.

`IDisposable` instances are persisted in a private field of the private implementation of the `IDisposer` interface. Each `ILifetimeScope` contains its own `IDisposer` instances and there is no way to get all active `ILifetimescope` without keeping track of lifetimescope creation.

Keeping track of instances creation is not as heavy as it seems. Links you provide are good start point to implement such a feature. Don't forget to use `WeakReference` and `ConditionalWeakTable` to avoid any memory leak.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a `WeakReference`, if you just keep a running count?

Comment: @grokky you need `WeakReference` only if you want to access instance. If you only want to count them you don't need it.