# How to build a graph of resolved instances with Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac, graph-theory, ioc-container

After all registrations, I am doing `ContainerBuilder.RegisterCallback` and subscribing to all `IComponentRegistration.Preparing` and `IComponentRegistration.Activating` events to be able to handle all activations. With this two events I am able to build a tree, the order of events looks like this:

- Preparing: Root

  - Preparing: FirstLevel_A
  - Activating: FirstLevel_A
  - Preparing: FirstLevel_B

    - Preparing: SecondLevel_C
    - Activating: SecondLevel_C
  - Activating: FirstLevel_B
- Activating: Root

But what if some registrations are not `Per Dependency` and I will have a graph instead of a tree. Is it possible to handle this case?

Comment: I want to build something like "execution plan" on initial `Resolve` call and then propose a user to execute it (call a method) or not. I don't want to model this behavior in all components I have in a container, looking for a fast solution.

Comment: I know there are few assumptions involved: should be no side effects in constructors/destructors (it's ok); some dependencies can be misleading (I'm hiding them). But in general it should work, except this case in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600468/1943849) there's another way of handling these events:

> If you want to get fancier, you can set up some event handlers on the
>   container `ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning`, `ResolveOperationBeginning`,
>   `ResolveOperationEnding`, and `CurrentScopeEnding` events.
>
> - During `ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning` you'd need to set up something to
>     automatically attach to any child lifetime `ResolveOperationBeginning`
>     events.
> - During `ResolveOperationBeginning` you'd log what is going to be
>     resolved.
> - During `ResolveOperationEnding` you'd log any exceptions
>     coming out.
> - During `CurrentScopeEnding` you'd need to unsubscribe from
>     any events on that scope so the garbage collector can clean up the
>     lifetime scope with all of its instances.

It's harder, but should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but it is too big for a comment.

AutoFac is a great IoC container, but it has 2 major problems. One is the awful registration API and the other one is a complete lack of diagnostics. The original author of AutoFac once tried to create an application that would help with this: [Whitebox](https://github.com/nblumhardt/whitebox). The development has stopped and moved on to [Autofac Analysis](https://github.com/autofac/autofac-analysis), that hasn't been active in years.

What you want to do requires a lot of insight into the inner workings of AutoFac, so you might want to check out the sources for ideas on how to accomplish what you need.