# How to convert IServiceCollection registrations to Autofac registrations?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Wonderful `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection` has a lot of extensions associated with it.

One example is `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions` and `AddConsole(this ILoggingBuilder builder)` method which registers `ConsoleLoggerProvider` in `ILoggingBuilder.Services` property of type `IServiceCollection`.

So, the logical question for anyone using Autofac. How to re-use all this extensions? Is there's a way to convert all `IServiceCollection` registrations to `ContainerBuilder` registrations?

Comment: That's not the logical question. It's actually the other way around. If you are using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, you should register all your AutoFac components with it, and then use it to resolve your dependencies.

Comment: @mason I'm using Autofac with all features available in it. Sorry, it's not a sample application, I can't change IoC container to be able to use those extensions. Just wondering, if there's already an easy way to do it

Comment: What features are you using that makes you not able to migrate?

Comment: Check out my last question if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318662/how-to-build-a-graph-of-resolved-instances-with-autofac

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting [`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection) registrations into Autofac is the whole point of the `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package. That's the integration for Autofac with .NET Core. [There is plenty of doc and examples on how to get going.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html)

By the way, this sort of adapter pattern isn't specific to Autofac. This conversion sort of thing is how most of the other DI frameworks back the conforming container in [`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection). If you happen to switch away from Autofac for some reason, check out the docs on those frameworks because they all have some sort of integration library.