# Measure and monitor Autofac resolve time of individual components

Tags: dependencies, autofac, autofac-configuration

There is reply for the same question here but that is for old Autofac:
[How to measure and monitor Autofac resolve time of individual components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441419/how-to-measure-and-monitor-autofac-resolve-time-of-individual-components)

New version of Autofac is not exposing Preparing & Activating method any more.
Can some one please help me to get the measurement of Autofac Rsolve time for each component.

Comment: [Have you read the docs on diagnostics?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html)

Comment: diagnostics are not containing time, only the hierarchy of the autofac pipeline